# How to maintain a job history using Quartz scheduler

Tags: c#, java, task, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to maintain a history of jobs that were scheduled by a Quartz scheduler containing the following properties: 'start time', 'end time', 'success', 'error'.

There are two interfaces available for this: `ITriggerListener` and `IJobListener` (I'm using the C# naming convention for interfaces because I'm using Quartz.NET but the same question could be asked for the Java version).

`IJobListener` has a `JobToBeExecuted` and a `JobWasExecuted` method. The latter provides a `JobExecutionException` so that you know when something went wrong. However, there is no way to correlate `JobToBeExecuted` and `JobWasExecuted`. Suppose my job runs for ten minutes. I start it at `t0` and `t0+2` (so they overlap). I get two calls to `JobToBeExecuted` and insert two start times into my history table. When both jobs finish at `t1` and `t1+2` I get two calls to `JobWasExecuted`. How do I know what database record to update in each call (to store an end time with its corresponding start time)?

`ITriggerListener` has another problem. There is no way to get any errors inside the `TriggerComplete` method when a job failed.

How do I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to do this is to generate an identifier in `JobToBeExecuted`, store it in the `JobExecutionContext` and retrieve it again from the `JobExecutionContext` in `JobWasExecuted`.

```
public void JobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context)
{
    // Insert history record and retrieve primary key of inserted record.
    long historyId = InsertHistoryRecord(...);
    context.Put("HistoryIdKey", historyId);
}

public void JobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
                           JobExecutionException jobException)
{
    // Retrieve history id from context and update history record.
    long historyId = (long) context.Get("HistoryIdKey");
    UpdateHistoryRecord(historyId, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The scheduler has to maintain a key that lets it correlate each history entry.  There must be a unique job ID of some kind that's created when a job kicks off to be able to accomplish this.

You don't mention such a thing, so I thought it was worth a suggestion.

UPDATE: I'd INSERT a record into the database when a job is created and get back the primary key (maybe a GUID).  I'd use that as the key.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I could find such a key?

Comment: Currently the key is JobGroup, JobName and the date and time.  It appears that a better key is coming in the 2.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to just update the database at the end, you can get the job name and run time from the `IJobExecutionContext`:

```
public void JobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
                       JobExecutionException jobException)
{
    var sql = @"INSERT INTO MyJobAuditHistory 
                (JobKey, RunTime, Status, Exception) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    // create command etc.
    command.Parameters.Add(context.JobDetail.Key.ToString());
    command.Parameters.Add(context.JobRunTime);
    command.Parameters.Add(jobException == null ? "Success" : "Fail");
    command.Parameters.Add(jobException == null ? null : jobException.Message);
}
```