# Quartz.NET auditing

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm going to be using Quartz.NET for a Windows Service I am creating.

I require all jobs carried out to be audited into a separate table (QRTZ_AUDIT) after completion or after failure, but is there a built in way of doing this?

I could simply manually open up connections to both the jobs table and the audit table and copy the relevant row to the audit table, but it seems like a lot of effort when there may be built in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [implement](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson07.html) the [`IJobListener`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic27.html) interface for this. You register this listener to the scheduler using [`AddGlobalJobListener`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic42.html).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955818/how-to-maintain-a-job-history-using-quartz-scheduler) for more information.